# Верстка горизонтального меню на CSS flex

Tags: css, flexbox, menu

Делаю горизонтальное меню на css. Нужно добиться эффекта, чтобы пункты меню (элементы li в которых a-ссылки) занимали всё место в блоке меню по горизонтали. Иными словами чтоб когда наводишь мышкой, ховер загорался от края до края, а не только на ширину слова в пункте меню.

Для наглядности прикладываю 2 скрина. Первый как надо сделать, второй - как получается сейчас

[image: Как надо сделать]

[image: Как получается сейчас]

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
}

nav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-around;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: black;
}

nav li {
 display: flex;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 
}

nav a {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 
}

nav a:hover {
 background-color: #1A3039;
}
```

```html
<nav>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
          </nav>
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для тега `li` добавил `flex: 1;`, для `a` - `width: 100%`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

nav li {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #1A3039;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: При наведении на первый и последний пункт меню остается черная полоса

Comment: @Leks, черная полоса из-за того, что автор не обнулил стили у `ul`, `li`. Поправил пример.

Comment: Указал на недочет т.к. у Вас получалось немного не то что хотел автор вопроса (без обид)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. оказалось не хватало немногого) я еще пока до свойства flex: 1 не добрался. А стили у меня просто вначале для всего обнулены.

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
}
ul a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li:hover{
  background-color: #1A3039;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо и вам тоже. У вас всё несколько сложнее, так как я пока еще не знаю всех этих свойств, начинающихся с дефиса.

Comment: @Ivan Zhukov эти св-ва можно нагуглить и прочитать за 5 минут